# Mad Lib program not running due to NameError?

Tags: tkinter, nameerror, defined

My code isn't working at all but I'm new to GUIs and cannot identify the problem.  Can anyone help?

Code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
""" GUI App to allow for the story based on user input"""

def _init_(self, master):
    """ Initialize frame."""
    Frame._init_(self, master)
    self.grid()
    self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        """ Create widgets to get information and display"""
        # create instruction label here
        Label(self,
              text = "It's Story Time.  Enter information for a new story"
              ).grid(row =0, column = 0, columnspan = 2, stiky = W)

        # create label and text entry for the human name
        Label(self,
              text = "Human: "
              ).grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)
        self.human_ent = Entry(self)
        self.juman_ent.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)

        # label for plural noun
        Label(self,
              text = "Plural Noun:"
              ).grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)
        self.noun_ent = Entry(self)
        self.noun_ent.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)

        # label for verbs
        Label(self,
              text = "Verb:"
              ).grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W)
        self.verb_ent = Entry(self)
        self.verb_ent.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)

        # label for adjective check button
        Label(self,
              text = "Adjective:"
              ).grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = W)

        # create bonkers button
        self.is_bonkers = BooleanVar()
        CheckButton(self,
                    text = "bonkers",
                    variable = self.is_bonk
                    ).grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = W)

        # create free-loading button
        self.is_free = BooleanVar()
        CheckButton(self,
                    text = "free-loading",
                    variable = self.is_free
                    ).grid(row = 4, column = 2, sticky = W)
        # create indecent button
        self.is_indecent = BooleanVar()
        CheckButton(self,
                    text = "indecent",
                    variable = self.is_indecent
                    ).grid(row = 4, column = 3, sticky = W)

        # radio buttons
        # label for body parts (I'm not creative)
        Label(self,
              text = "Body Part:"
              ).grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = W)

        # variables for single body part
        self.body_part = StringVar()

        # body parts radio buttons
        body_parts = ["bum", "ear lobe", "tailbone"]

        column = 1
        for part in body_parts:
            RadioButton(self,
                        text = part,
                        variable = self.body_part,
                        value = part
                        ).grid(row = 5, column = column, sticky = W)
            column += 1

            # create a submit button
            Button(self,
                   text = "Click for Awesome Story!",
                   command = self.tell_story
                   ).grid(row = 6, column = 0, sticky = W)

            self.story_txt = Test(self, width = 75, height = 10, wrap = WORD)
            self.story_txt.grid(row = 7, column = 0, columnspan = 4)


            # Application Class's tell_story() Method
            def tell_story(self):
                """ Fill text box with new story with user input. """
                # get values from the GUI
                human = self.human_ent.get()
                noun = self.noun_ent.get()
                verb = self.verb_ent.get()
                adjectives = ""
                if self.is_bonkers.get():
                    adjectives += "bonkers, "
                if self.is_free.get():
                    adjectives += "free-loading, "
                if self.is_indecent.get():
                    adjectives += "indecent, "
                body_part = self.body_part.get()

                # do hardest part (make story)
                story = "Once upon a time, there lived a mighty beast nameed "
                story += human
                story += "who lived in the dreaded Castle of "
                story += noun.title()
                story += "when, upon the Strawberry Moon, the "
                story += noun
                story += "unearthed "
                story += human + ". "
                story += "A "
                story += adjectives
                story += "thought ran through the beast's mind. "
                story += "The thought sparked something in the mind of "
                story += human
                story += "and soon the beast felt hungy for "
                story += body_part + ". "
                story += "So the beast searched for some "
                story += body_part + "flesh. "
                story += "Suddenly, the "
                story += noun
                story += "ran as quickly as possible, but it was too late.  "
                story += human + "had feasted."
                story += "The moral of the story?  Heed the warning of the Strawberry Moon, else "
                story += verb
                story += "to your doom."

                # display sad story
                self.story_txt.delete(0.0, END)
                self.story_txt.insert(0.0, story)

# Main Part of program goes here:

root = Tk()

root.title("The Strawberry Moon Mad Lib")

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Error reads:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/, Assignment 2a.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Application(Frame):
  File "C:/Users/HP/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/, Assignment 2a.py", line 148, in Application
    app = Application(root)
NameError: name 'Application' is not defined
```

I don't understand what this means nor how it is to be fixed. Any help is welcomed.

Thank you!

Comment: I do not get that error when I run your code. Also, you need to fix the indentation of your code, and it would help if you removed all of the irrelevant code. We really don't need a big long story variable or a bunch of widgets if the problem is in the app starting up.

Comment: I see a few issues with your code. `CheckButton` needs to be `Checkbutton`, `RadioButton` needs to be `Radiobutton`, `self.story_txt = Test()` needs to be `self.story_txt = Text()`, `self.juman_ent` should be `self.human_ent`. There is also some serious indention issues in your code that will prevent your code from working at all. You are missing variables and you have typos.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I'm embarrassed and wrote this quickly.  Can you explain the indention issues?  I'm used to MATLAB.

Comment: @ErinWinkler Your incomplete `init` method in the class is not indented correctly. It must be 4 spaces inward below the class. You have rows and a function indented below `for part in body_parts:` and they should not be. the `init` method needs to have double underscores instead of a single. If you compare my answer with your question you can review the differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overall problem with your code is typos and indention. The error message you are getting is probably being caused by the indention but even with that corrected you will end up getting error after error due to many typos.

I have cleaned up you code a bit and made it fit better with the PEP8 standards.
Some things you may want to change for readability. However the format is generally correct.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        tk.Label(self, text="It's Story Time.  Enter information for a new story").grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="w")
        tk.Label(self, text="Human: ").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.human_ent = tk.Entry(self)
        self.human_ent.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="w")

        tk.Label(self, text="Plural Noun:").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.noun_ent = tk.Entry(self)
        self.noun_ent.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="w")

        tk.Label(self, text="Verb:").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.verb_ent = tk.Entry(self)
        self.verb_ent.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="w")

        tk.Label(self, text="Adjective:").grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.is_bonkers = tk.BooleanVar()
        tk.Checkbutton(self, text="bonkers", variable=self.is_bonkers).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky="w")

        self.is_free = tk.BooleanVar()
        tk.Checkbutton(self, text="free-loading", variable=self.is_free).grid(row=4, column=2, sticky="w")

        self.is_indecent = tk.BooleanVar()
        tk.Checkbutton(self, text="indecent", variable=self.is_indecent).grid(row=4, column=3, sticky="w")

        tk.Label(self, text="Body Part:").grid(row=5, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.body_part = tk.StringVar()
        body_parts = ["bum", "ear lobe", "tailbone"]

        column = 1
        for part in body_parts:
            tk.Radiobutton(self, text=part, variable=self.body_part, value=part).grid(row=5, column=column, sticky="w")
            column += 1

        tk.Button(self, text="Click for Awesome Story!", command=self.tell_story).grid(row=6, column=0, sticky="w")
        self.story_txt = tk.Text(self, width=75, height=10, wrap="word")
        self.story_txt.grid(row=7, column=0, columnspan=4)

    def tell_story(self):
        human = self.human_ent.get()
        noun = self.noun_ent.get()
        verb = self.verb_ent.get()
        adjectives = ""
        if self.is_bonkers.get():
            adjectives += "bonkers, "
        if self.is_free.get():
            adjectives += "free-loading, "
        if self.is_indecent.get():
            adjectives += "indecent, "
        body_part = self.body_part.get()

        story = "Once upon a time, there lived a mighty beast named "
        story += human
        story += "who lived in the dreaded Castle of "
        story += noun.title()
        story += "when, upon the Strawberry Moon, the "
        story += noun
        story += "unearthed "
        story += human + ". "
        story += "A "
        story += adjectives
        story += "thought ran through the beast's mind. "
        story += "The thought sparked something in the mind of "
        story += human
        story += "and soon the beast felt hungry for "
        story += body_part + ". "
        story += "So the beast searched for some "
        story += body_part + "flesh. "
        story += "Suddenly, the "
        story += noun
        story += "ran as quickly as possible, but it was too late.  "
        story += human + "had feasted."
        story += "The moral of the story?  Heed the warning of the Strawberry Moon, else "
        story += verb
        story += "to your doom."

        self.story_txt.delete("1.0", "end")
        self.story_txt.insert("1.0", story)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("The Strawberry Moon Mad Lib")
app = Application(root).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This looks great and I'm embarrassed.  The nouns are not showing up though.

Comment: The noun portion does seam to be having problem let me try and find out why.

Comment: @ErinWinkler looks like the grid was not set up correctly for the noun entry field. I updated the code to correct the missing noun field

Comment: @ErinWinkler you don't need to be embarrassed. We have all made mistakes. I would just say slow down a little. Take a look at the PEP8 guidelines as they will help you be consistent.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I really appreciate the help.  I'm trying to do a new assignment now (ordering off a menu) so I'm hoping your help can get me to finish it soon.

Comment: If you run into a problem and you are unable to find a solution on here then ask your question and someone like myself will likely review your question.

Comment: Erin, Make sure if someone has answer your question and solved your problem to accept the answer with the check mark next to the best answer provided.